# SQL Server returning a constant as a named column based on LIKE

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have an existing SQL Expression that is working well I need to also return a named column that will return one of 2 values based on the existance of a suffix on a string.  Not too familiar with all the nuances of SQL and I can't seem to get the value to return - or the SQL to be happy.  It goes something like this:

```
DECLARE @LBC nvarchar(3) = 'LBC'
DECLARE @CBD nvarchar(3) = 'CBD'

CASE WHEN tblWellReadingResult_7.test_code LIKE '%CBD%' THEN
@CBD 
ELSE (SELECT @LBC) AS [AssayType],
```

Its squaking about the AS keyword. Tried using an IF statement with similar errors.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please be aware that tags can not be combined to create concepts.  That is, combining the tags `sql` and `server` does not mean your question is about MS SQL Server.  There is a dedicated tag just for SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

You just need an END (for both CASE and IF)

Also, remove the SELECT in (SELECT @LBC) so you just have @LBC

```
DECLARE @LBC nvarchar(3) = 'LBC'
DECLARE @CBD nvarchar(3) = 'CBD'

CASE WHEN tblWellReadingResult_7.test_code LIKE '%CBD%' 
     THEN @CBD 
     ELSE @LBC 
END AS [AssayType],
```

or

```
IF tblWellReadingResult_7.test_code LIKE '%CBD%' THEN @CBD ELSE @LBC END AS AssayType,
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an `END` to your case expression.

```
CASE WHEN tblWellReadingResult_7.test_code LIKE '%CBD%' THEN @CBD  
    ELSE @LBC END AS [AssayType],
```

Comment: Beat me by 1 second -- but I had more letters in mine! :)

Comment: Oh -- and also, note that this is a case *expression*, not a case *statement*.

Comment: @ruakh - thanks for the clarification, I was in the process of update the select statement.

Comment: Sorry and thanks - wish my glass prescription was up to date :)

Answer (score 0):

why select and variables ?

more easy:

```
--select 
CASE WHEN tblWellReadingResult_7.test_code LIKE '%CBD%' THEN
'LBC' 
ELSE 'LBC' END AS [AssayType] --, and another fields
-- From yourTable
```

Comment: Maybe those are changing in other parts of the query?